# Google Webmaster showing 410 on pages removed 6 years ago

Tags: google-search-console, http-status-code-410

We redeveloped a site in 2012 that had been a simple HTML page catalog site. It became a dynamic, SOLR-driven site under the same domain name. The site content is updated daily (although not all products change daily) and there are now nearly 300,000 products. XML sitemaps of the new site are uploaded daily. About 2 years ago we moved the site to HTTPS.

Google Webmaster is still reporting pages from the old site (blah-blah.html) in the the Crawl Errors under Not Found. All the pages are showing status 410. Here's the relevant part of the vhosts 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*).html$
    RewriteRule .* - [G,NC]`

We cannot see where Google is finding these dead pages after 6 years! We remove them in Webmaster and mark them as fixed but they keep coming back.

How long do we have to wait before Google stops 'finding' them? How can we find where Google may be finding old backlinks - there aren't any showing in search?

Comment: Maybe some third party still has links to these dead pages? You could recreate said pages and log the referer, that could give you a hint.

Comment: Fair point but we're seeing hundreds of pages with .html suffix and Webmaster shows linking sites with only a handful of pages and mainly the homepage at that. Definitely seems to be a Google issue.

Comment: Google doesn't care - they are indexing 410 pages that are years old and have been submitted numerous times to the "remove this" tool. The same with year-old 404s or even websites that are 100% gone from the www.